# play evolution is not being applied in production heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.3.5 application in heroku. It was running off the base evolution 1.sql.
Now I pushed a new release, but the new 2.sql is not being picked up.

I logged into the heroku console (heroku run bash) to check first-hand. The applyEvolutions.default=true is both in config file:

```
~ $ egrep -v '^($|#)' target/universal/stage/conf/application.conf 
application.secret="..................."
application.langs="en"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?DATABASE_URL}
applyEvolutions.default=true
ebean.default="models.*"
logger.root=ERROR
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=DEBUG
```

and command line:

```
~ $ cat runheroku.sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS='/@: ' read -a array <<< "${DATABASE_URL}"
user="${array[3]}"
pass="${array[4]}"

echo $user $pass
target/universal/stage/bin/play-java -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true    -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.user=$user -Ddb.default.password=$pass
```

I am using heroku postgres (amazon) and the only evolution marked there is 1:

```
$ psql -h ec2-54-83-43-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p .... - d .... - U .... -W
=> select id,state  from play_evolutions ;
 id |  state  
----+---------
  1 | applied
(1 row)
```

Just to be clear, both evolution files are there:

```
~ $ ls -l target/universal/stage/conf/evolutions/default/
total 12
-rw------- 1 uxxxxx xxxxx 6104 Dec 15 09:46 1.sql
-rw------- 1 uxxxxx xxxxx  132 Dec 15 09:46 2.sql
```

However, upon restart, the app doesn't seem to do any evolutions:

```
2014-12-15T09:48:31+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-12-15T09:48:31.341979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-12-15T09:48:34.066394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-12-15T09:48:35.595535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-12-15T09:48:38.198778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./runheroku.sh`
2014-12-15T09:48:39.181686+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2014-12-15T09:48:39.620271+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 4
2014-12-15T09:48:41.419851+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-83-43-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-15T09:48:42.914391+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Application started (Prod)
2014-12-15T09:48:43.186820+00:00 app[web.1]: [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:36021
2014-12-15T09:48:43.255944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

What did I miss (or mess) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it ... basically, I have exceeded the row limit of free DB on heroku (10,000 rows) and the postgres user was denied inserts. Interestingly, this is all failing silently, so I had to manually execute the evolution to have the application load - and then, upon my first operation that involved an insert, the app failed with a proper exception.

In the end, I:

- got the paid version of DB
- migrated the data from a snapshot in the old DB using pg:restore
- restarted the app - this failed (the evolution could not be applied again)
- manually rolled back the evolution in the new DB
- restarted the app - this failed (the evolution attempt was already registered)
- went back to the old DB, rolled back the manual evolution there
- migrated a fresh snapshot of old DB into the new DB
- restarted ...

and voila, evolution was applied properly.